# PostgreSQL - insert statement error, thinks value to insert is a column name

Tags: postgresql

I'm running PostgreSQL version 9.5.1 on my Mac - I'm trying to make a simple insert statement, but it's spitting an error that I don't quite understand... for some reason, it seems to think that one of the values that I'm inserting is actually one of the column names.  Here's the scenario...

`\d+ group_members`

```
Column      |            Type             |
------------+-----------------------------+
id          | integer                     |
group_id    | integer                     |
user_id     | integer                     |
role        | character varying(255)      |
inserted_at | timestamp without time zone |
updated_at  | timestamp without time zone |

Indexes:
  "group_members_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
  "group_members_group_id_index" btree (group_id)
  "group_members_user_id_index" btree (user_id)
```

When I try to run

```
insert into group_members (group_id, user_id, role, inserted_at, updated_at)
values (1, 2, ’member’, current_timestamp, current_timestamp);
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR:  column "’member’" does not exist
LINE 1: ...user_id,role,inserted_at,updated_at) values (1,2,’member’,c...
                                                            ^
```

Well yes, I agree, the column 'member' does not exist... but I'm not sure I understand why PostgreSQL thinks that this is my intention.  I have made numerous inserts into other tables and had now such problem but I can't seem to insert into this table.  Can anyone see where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `’member’` with `'member'` .

It seems you dont have single quote. it is some other char

Comment: Holy crap, you're right!  I have no idea how that happened, I'm not kidding.  I had a feeling this would be some embarrassing error on my part.

Comment: Well, this happens. Happy Coding!

Comment: This solved it for me in Spring Boot too! thank you